# Haskell runtime error : UnsuccessfulReturnCode "odbc_SQLExecDirectW" (-1)

Tags: sql, sql-server, haskell, runtime-error

at the moment I'm writing a small program which runs a couple SQLServer queries. To make the queries type-save I created a module "SQLQuery" which lets you design queries in a save way.

To execute the queries they have to be of type **Query** thus I did the following...

```
toSql $ 
T.pack (show (SELECT [Column "name"] (FROM (Table "kundenDBs")) (WHERE [AND (condition "activeProdData" Eq "'true'")]) NothingGB (ORDERBY [Column "name"] ASC)))
```

My Main.hs code is...

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Database.ODBC.SQLServer
import           Data.ByteString
import qualified Data.Text as T
import           SQLQuery  (AND (..), Column (..), Direction (..), FROM (..),
                            GROUPBY (..), ORDERBY (..), Operand (..),
                            Operator (..), SELECT (..), Table (..), WHERE (..),
                            condition)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  conn <- connectToDB
  selectGipscommDB conn
  clients <- queryClients conn
  selectClientDB conn
  orders <- queryOrders conn
  print clients
  print orders

  -- Produces valid sql string (tested!)
  print $ show (SELECT [Column "name"] (FROM (Table "kundenDBs")) (WHERE [AND (condition "activeProdData" Eq "'true'")]) NothingGB (ORDERBY [Column "name"] ASC))

  close conn

connectToDB :: IO Connection
connectToDB =
    connect
      "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=xxx;Uid=yyy;Pwd=zzz"

selectGipscommDB :: Connection -> IO ()
selectGipscommDB =
    flip exec gipscommDB

gipscommDB :: Query
gipscommDB =
    "USE abc"

type Client = ByteString

queryClients :: Connection -> IO [Client]
queryClients =
    flip query clientsSql

clientsSql :: Query
clientsSql =
    toSql $ T.pack (show (SELECT [Column "name"] (FROM (Table "kundenDBs")) (WHERE [AND (condition "activeProdData" Eq "'true'")]) NothingGB (ORDERBY [Column "name"] ASC)))
    -- "SELECT name FROM kundenDBs WHERE activeProdData = 'true' ORDER BY name"

type Product = ByteString
type Order = ByteString

queryOrders :: Connection -> IO [(Product, Order)]
queryOrders = flip query ordersSql

ordersSql :: Query
ordersSql =
    "SELECT artikelnummer, auftrag FROM ProdData_ WHERE artikelnummer <> '' AND auftrag <> '' GROUP BY auftrag, artikelnummer ORDER BY artikelnummer"

selectClientDB :: Connection -> IO ()
selectClientDB =
    flip exec clientDB

clientDB :: Query
clientDB =
    "USE xyz"
```

My SQLQuery module code is...

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module SQLQuery where

import           Data.List               (intercalate)
import           Data.Maybe              (fromMaybe)
import           Data.String             (IsString (fromString))
import qualified Data.Text               as T
import           Database.ODBC.SQLServer


-- SELECT
--
data SELECT
    = SELECT [Column] FROM WHERE GROUPBY ORDERBY

instance Show SELECT where
    show (SELECT cols from where' groupBy orderBy) =
        "SELECT " ++ join ", " cols ++ " " ++ show from  ++ " " ++ show where' ++ " " ++ show groupBy ++ " " ++ show orderBy


-- FROM
--
newtype FROM = FROM Table

instance Show FROM where
    show (FROM tbl) = "FROM " ++ show tbl


-- WHERE
--
data WHERE
    = WHERE [AND]
    | NothingW

instance Show WHERE where
    show (WHERE ands) = "WHERE " ++ join " AND " ands
    show NothingW     = ""


-- AND
--
newtype AND = AND Condition

instance Show AND where
    show (AND cond) = show cond


--GROUPBY
--
data GROUPBY
    = GROUPBY [Column]
    | NothingGB

instance Show GROUPBY where
    show (GROUPBY cols) = "GROUP BY " ++ join ", " cols
    show NothingGB      = ""


-- ORDERBY
--
newtype ORDERBY = ORDERBY [Column]

instance Show ORDERBY where
    show (ORDERBY cols) = "ORDER BY " ++ join ", " cols


-- Table
--
newtype Table = Table String

instance Show Table where
    show (Table tbl) = tbl


-- Column
--
data Column = Column String Direction

instance Show Column where
    show (Column col dir) = col ++ " " ++ show dir


-- Condition
--
data Condition
    = Condition Operand Operator Operand

instance Show Condition where
    show (Condition operand1 operator operand2) = show operand1 <> show operator <> show operand2

condition :: String -> Operator -> String -> Condition
condition operand1 operator operand2 =
    Condition (Operand operand1) operator (Operand operand2)


-- Operand
--
newtype Operand = Operand String

instance Show Operand where
    show (Operand operand) = operand


-- Operator
--
data Operator
    = Eq
    | Ueq
    | Gt
    | Lt

instance Show Operator where
    show Eq  = " = "
    show Ueq = " <> "
    show Gt  = " > "
    show Lt  = " < "


-- Direction
--
data Direction
    = ASC
    | DESC

instance Show Direction where
    show ASC  = "ASC"
    show DESC = "DESC"


-- Functions
--
join :: Show a => String -> [a] -> String
join str = intercalate str . map show
```

which type check but lead to an error at runtime...

```
UpdateProdData-exe.EXE: UnsuccessfulReturnCode "odbc_SQLExecDirectW" (-1) "[Microsoft][ODBC 
Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]In EXECUTE <procname>, procname can only be a literal or 
variable of type char, varchar, nchar, or nvarchar.[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]In EXECUTE <procname>, procname can only be a literal or variable of type char, 
varchar, nchar, or nvarchar."
```

Well, I have no clue how to resolve this issue so I would be thankful if someone could help me. :)

Comment: Looks like you are getting an error from SQL Server because it doesn't like something in the SQL generated by the Haskell SQLQuery library. Can you find out what that SQL query string actually was?

Comment: Also, have you tried just sending a simple string to SQL Server to see if that part of the process works?

Comment: I printed out the query, and know that the correct query is produced as a string. So I guess that something due to the "toSql $ T.pack <query> has to produce the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Haskell ODBC library is designed to do string escaping. What seems to be happening is that `toSql "String"` wraps up the contents of the string as an escaped SQL string, not an unescaped query.

If you use `fromString myQuery` instead of `toSQL $ T.pack myQuery` it should work.

Comment: @HangoverSoundSound When you get the right answer here you should click the up arrow next to it, and also the tick mark to flag it as accepted.

Comment: I clicked the checked sign but I'm not yet allowed to click the up arrow. Just started using stackoverflow...